# I am having a problem with the cause modifies in Dafny

Tags: dafny

I am trying to make a valid queue object and method in Dafny, but I am having problem with the clause modifies, as I cannot enqueue a value into the queue due to the error `call might violate context's modifies clauseVerifier`

this is the code:

```
class {:autocontract} Fila {
    var fila: array<int>;
    var head: int;
    var tail: int;

    constructor ()
        ensures Valid();
    {
        fila := new int[5];
        head, tail:= 0, -1;
    }

    predicate Valid()
        reads this
    {
        -1 <= tail < fila.Length &&
        0 <= head < fila.Length
    }

    function isEmpty(): bool
        requires Valid()
        reads this
    {
        tail == -1
    }

    method Enqueue(x: int)
    requires Valid()
    modifies this, fila
    ensures Valid() 
    ensures tail == old(tail) + 1
    ensures head == old(head)
    ensures fila[tail] == x
    {
        if tail + 1 == fila.Length {
             DoubleSize();        
        }
        tail := tail + 1;
        fila[tail] := x;
    }


    method DoubleSize() 
        requires Valid()
        modifies this, fila
        ensures Valid() 
        ensures fresh(fila)
        ensures fila.Length == old(fila.Length) * 2
        ensures tail == old(tail) && head == old(head)        
        ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < old(fila.Length) ==> fila[i] == old(fila[i])
        {
            var aux := new int[2 * fila.Length];
            var i: int := 0;
            while i < fila.Length
                invariant 0 <= i <= fila.Length
                invariant forall j :: 0 <= j < i ==> aux[j] == fila[j]
                modifies aux
            {
                aux[i] := fila[i];
                i := i + 1;
            }
             fila := aux;
        }

}

method Main()
{
    var fila := new Fila();

    fila.Enqueue(2);
    
    print(fila.isEmpty());
}
```

I tried to enqueue 2 to fila, and it didn't work because of said error, but dafny doesn't tell me any other error in the previous methods and codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add

```
ensures fresh(fila)
```

to your constructor.